# References between entities in JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a Question entity and a QuestionCategory entity in my application. In the database this is a many-to-many relationship. I could need some help with this.

Should I create a List reference in the Question that references QuestionCategory and visa verca? And then JPA can automatically fetch the categories or questions depending on which entity you start out with.

Or should you not have references between them and then use JPQL as named queries instead for retrieving the questions belonging to the category, or categories belonging to the questions depending on what you are after?

I don't know if I use the references to much, or not. How do you descide this?

Comment: Why many-to-many in the database and not just a category column in the question table as a foreign key from the question_category table?

Answer (score 0):

JPA providers do support many to many relations. So you can put lists as you mentioned & mark it with proper ManyToMany annotation & join column names & JAP will do rest of the work for you. BTW which JPA provider you have??? Like hibernate, IBatis etc??

Code example: http://www.roseindia.net/jpa/eclipsejpaexamples/jparelationship/many-to-many.shtml

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Bidirectional` relationship in `ManyToMany`. The main things is to take care the usage of `CascadeType`. 
Based on your `CascadeType` type usage, there may be unnecessary problems. In my example, `Manager` and `Project` are `ManyToMay` relationship.

**Example :**

Manager.java

```
@Entity
public class Manager implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "managers", cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private List<Project> projects;

    public Manager() {
        projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    }

    public Manager(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    }

    //getter and setter

    public void add(Project project) {
        if (!projects.contains(project)) {
            projects.add(project);
        }
        if (!project.getManagers().contains(this)) {
            project.getManagers().add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Project.java

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PROJ_DEP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROJ_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID"))
    private List<Manager> managers;

    public Project() {
        managers = new ArrayList<Manager>();
    }

    public Project(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        managers = new ArrayList<Manager>();
    }

    //getter and setter

    public void add(Manager manager) {
        if (!managers.contains(manager)) {
            managers.add(manager);
        }
        if (!manager.getProjects().contains(this)) {
            manager.getProjects().add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

ManyToManyTest.java

```
public class ManyToManyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Project p1 = new Project("Project 1");
        Project p2 = new Project("Project 2");
        Project p3 = new Project("Project 3");

        Manager m1 = new Manager("Jon");
        m1.add(p1);
        m1.add(p2);
        m1.add(p3);

        Manager m2 = new Manager("Kone");
        m2.add(p2); 
        m2.add(p3);

        em.persist(m1);
        em.persist(m2);

        System.out.println("Success..");
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

    }
}
```

Assume `CascadeType.REMOVE` or `CascadeType.ALL` contain in `Manager` entity.

1. There are two manager m1 and m2. m1 have three projects p1, p2 and p3. m2 have two projects p1 and p2.
2. If m1 has removed, the related projects p1, p2 and p3 will removed automatically.
3. Here, problem is there is no projects record of m2.

   ```
   /*Kone's projects record will be loss.*/
   Manager m = (Manager)em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Manager m WHERE m.name = 'Jon' ").getSingleResult();
   em.remove(m);
   ```

Assume `CascadeType.PERSIST` or `CascadeType.ALL` contain in `Manager` entity.

1. If you would like to persist a `Manager`, its projects may be new and existing record.
2. For new instance of `Project` will be new record.
3. The existing instance of `Project`(By query) will be reference.

   ```
   /*When m3 has persisted, p2 will be new record in Project table. p1 will be just reference.*/
   Project p1 = (Project)em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Project m WHERE m.name = 'Project 1' ").getSingleResult();
   Project p2 = new Project("Project 1"); 

   Manager m3 = new Manager("Nexz");
   em.persist(m3);
   ```

My suggestion is to use `CascadeType.REFRESH`, whatever you create `Manager`  or `Project` the reference will be retrieve from database by query.